# Asignar la misma función JavaScript a tres botones y que funcionen por separado

Tags: javascript

Quiero poner tres botones y que cada uno incremente su valor al hacer clic sobre él. Les asigno la misma función, pero lo que consigo es que sume los clics de los tres:

```html
<body>
<body>
```

```html
<h3>Haz click en los botones y sabrás cuántas veces lo has hecho</h3>

<button type="button" class="botonClic">Botón 1</button>
<button type="button" class="botonClic">Botón 2</button>
<button type="button" class="botonClic">Botón 3</button>

<script>
  var valor = 0;
  var botones = document.getElementsByClassName("botonClic");

  for (var i = 0; i < botones.length; i++) {
    botones[i].onclick = function() {
      valor = valor + 1;
      this.textContent = valor;
    };
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes conseguir el efecto deseado cambiando un poco la estructura HTML, es decir, esta:

```html
<button type="button" class="botonClic">Botón 1</button>
...
```

Por esta otra:

```html
<div class="buttons">
    <button type="button" class="botonClic" data-number="0">Botón 1</button>
...
</div>
```

Y utilizar delegación de eventos.

> Note que se ha agregado el atributo `data-number="0"` para obtener un valor inicial a partir de él.

### Ejemplo completo

Ahora que tenemos claro lo anterior podemos reproducir el ejemplo completo que será explicado más abajo:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelector(".buttons");

buttons.onclick = (e) => {
  const control = e.target;
  let valor;
  
  if ( control.dataset.number ) {
    // El valor inicial de valor es el valor del atributo
    // «data-number»:
    valor = Number(control.dataset.number);
    valor++;
    
    // Se actualiza el valor del atributo «data-number»
    control.dataset.number = valor;
    
    // Luego se actualiza el texto del botón.
    control.textContent = valor;
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>Haz click en los botones y sabrás cuántas veces lo has hecho</h3>

<div class="buttons">
  <button type="button" class="botonClic" data-number="0">Botón 1</button>
  <button type="button" class="botonClic" data-number="0">Botón 2</button>
  <button type="button" class="botonClic" data-number="0">Botón 3</button>
</div>
```

#### Explicación

Obtenemos el botón con:

```js
const control = e.target;
```

> <sup>Recuerde que `e.target` puede ser cualquier elemento donde se haga clic, de allí, la importancia de identificar el elemento que nos interesa.</sup>

Creamos nuestra variable `valor`, que es la que actualizará el valor del atributo `data-number`:

```js
let valor;
```

Consultamos si el elemento objetivo (en este caso, el botón) tiene definido el atributo `data-number`:

```js
if ( control.dataset.number ) {
    ...
}
```

Obtenemos su valor inicial a partir de dicho atributo:

```js
valor = Number(control.dataset.number);
```

Actualizamos el valor del atributo `data-number`:

```js
valor++;
control.dataset.number = valor
```

Y finalmente, el texto del botón:

```js
control.textContent = valor;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por todo. Tu explicación ha sido de gran ayuda.